Parsing a polymorphic YAML file in C#
I have a YAML config file that defines a navigation structure. The root node is a sequence and each child of this sequence can either be a key-value pair or a sequence of key-value pairs. I need to be able to have this nesting go arbitrarily deep. (Heavily inspired by the mkdocs config file.)
Example of the YAML file:
navigation:
  - Introduction: "index.md"
  - Demo:
    - Introduction: "demo/index.md"
    - Some Other Page: "demo/otherpage.md"
  - Deeper Nesting:
    - Index: "deeper/index.md"
    - Subsection:
      - Index: "deeper/sub/index.md"
      - Sub-Sub Section:
        - Index: "deeper/sub/sub/index.md

Is something like this achievable with YamlDotNet or some other .NET YAML parsing library?
